# Bukkit - Health in name

Tags: java, bukkit

**FIXED**

I am attempting to add a health bar next to my entities name, like:

Level 3 Skeleton ||||

Where bars are how much health, out of 5.
I have tried everything it seems, but I cannot figure it out! I think its really simple, but I just can't get it...

```
@EventHandler
public void entityDamageEntity(EntityDamageEvent event) {
    LivingEntity entity = (LivingEntity) event.getEntity();
    if (entity.getCustomName() != null) {
        entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName().replaceAll("|", ""));
        int health = (int) Math.ceil(entity.getHealth() / entity.getMaxHealth() * 5);
        int i = 1;
        String healthbar = " |";
        while(i < health){
            i++;
            healthbar = healthbar + "|";
        }
        entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName() + healthbar);
    }
}
```

I just cannot seem to get it to work! It does weird things, try using it with a named entity. If someone could point out the error, that would be great =D

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYdcI.png

**FIXED CODE:**

```
@EventHandler
public void entityDamageEntity(EntityDamageEvent event) {
    LivingEntity entity = (LivingEntity) event.getEntity();
    if (entity.getCustomName() != null) {
        entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName().replaceAll("\\|", ""));
        int health = (int) ((float) entity.getHealth() / entity.getMaxHealth() *5);
        if (health > 0){
            char[] bars = new char[health + 1];
            Arrays.fill(bars, '|');
            entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName() + " " + new String(bars));
            entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName().replaceAll("  ", " "));
        } else {
            entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName()); 
            entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName().replaceAll("  ", " "));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So without going into the game, you have 1 major problem with the code (you are dividing two integers which is going to give you 0), and then an efficiency issue with appending strings.  Fixing the first

```
int health = (int) ((float) entity.getHealth() / entity.getMaxHealth() *5);
```

What you want to do now is append 0 through 5 health bars. The following will create an array of 1 through 5 '|'.  It is more efficient than a while loop as it just creates the needed array size directly, as opposed to using appending.

```
if (health > 0){
    char[] bars = new char[health];
    Arrays.fill(bars, '|');
    entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName()+" " + new String(bars));
} else {
    entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName()); // no bars to add
}
```

Comment: Thank you for figuring this out.

Comment: Yep. I had a problem with the
`entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName()+" " + new String(bars));`
Adding a space inbetween the entities name and the bars, so after that, I added:
`entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName().replaceAll("  ", " "));`

Answer (score 1):

I see an immediate problem here. `|` is a special character in regex, so you should escape this character.

Try:

```
entity.setCustomName(entity.getCustomName().replaceAll("\\|", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks you! I noticed it wasn't removing the bars, forgot it was a special character.